# Publish Pandas Dataframe rows as PubSub Message

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a task to publish the rows of a [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) as a [pubsub](/questions/tagged/pubsub) message.
What is the best to do this? My [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) could consist of around 1 million records.

This is an example I have found to publish.

```
for n in range(1, 10):
    data_str = f"Message number {n}"
    # Data must be a bytestring
    data = data_str.encode("utf-8")
    # When you publish a message, the client returns a future.
    future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data)
    print(future.result())
```

Can I loop through each row, convert the row to string, encode and publish like below?

```
for row_dict in df.to_dict(orient="records"):
    data = str(row_dict).encode("utf-8")
    future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data)
    print(future.result())
```

Or I'm I missing something simpler?
I would like the [pubsub](/questions/tagged/pubsub) message to be in a dict format with each message for a row like below.

```
{'col1': '123','col2': 'abc'}
{'col1': '124','col2': 'def'}
{'col1': '125','col2': 'ghi'}
{'col1': '126','col2': 'jkl'}
```

Comment: The code you want to apply is in the consumer part, to transform PubSubMessage to Dict ?

Comment: But how to publish the Pandas rows as a PubSubMessage?

Answer (score 1):

To publish the Pandas rows as a pubSubMessage you can consider the below example:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [123, 124, 125], 'col2': ['abc', 'abcd', 'abce']})

publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
topic_path = publisher.topic_path('demo_project', 'topic')

for row_index, row in df.iterrows():
    message = json.dumps(row.to_dict()).encode('utf-8')
    future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data=message)
    print(future.result())
print("Completed")
```

Result:

[image]

The above python code is just an example of publishing data frame records row by row.

When you are dealing with large amounts of data, it's important to consider the memory limitation. My suggestion is to use a chunksize parameter with panda.The parameter chunksize is the number of rows read at a time in a file by Pandas. This method returns an iterator TextFileReader which must be iterated to obtain the data.

Example:

```
pd.read_csv(‘file_name’, chunksize= size_chunk)
```

Instead of publishing messages one at a time, you can send several messages together.In this client library uses the batch feature to publish several messages together in one service call.

If cost is not a consideration, you can create multiple publisher clients and disable batch messaging. This process minimizes latency and maximizes throughput by scaling horizontally on the number of publishers. Sending multiple messages in a single publish request is one way to reach equivalent throughput with fewer publishers.

If you are willing to trade off some latency for cost savings, especially if your application deals with a fairly large number of messages within a short time period, you can use batch messaging.For more information you can follow this [link1](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher?hl=en#batching) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61730561/).Also keep in mind that pubsub has some quota and [limitation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas).

Comment: HI @kiran can you please let me know how the answer is different to the one I mentioned? I converted the dataframe to dict and then published one row. Your answer iterates each row and converts it to dict one row at a time. And also can you please suggest if there is any better way to publish?

Comment: Hi @AshokKS,I updated the answer. I hope I addressed your question.